# How to use a snowflake connector logged-on to account from a python script to fetch query results in multiple scripts without logging again

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, shared-ptr, shared-memory

I'm looking for global use of a snowflake connection across multiple scripts/notebooks simultaneously (asynchronous queries are supported by snowflake). Basic idea is to avoid keying in the credentials multiple times and to avoid multiple connections to Snowflake from the same python server instance.

###### obtaining user credentials

```
from getpass import getpass
account=input("accountName"); user = input("username:"); password = getpass("password:")
myCredentials=dict(account=account,user=user,password=password)
```

to attempt, I created connections via snowflake.sqlalchemy and snowflake.connector separately as below.

###### using SQLALCHEMY

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
engine = create_engine(URL(**myCredentials))
conn_alchemy = engine.connect()
```

###### using SNOWFLAKE CONNECTOR

```
import snowflake.connector as snflk
conn_snflk = snflk.connect(**myCredentials)
```

while the connections are established successfully, the attempt to share it with other notebooks were a failure.
for instance, **%store** magic function was suggested from online threads, but it failed to pickle the connector(s).

#### expected functionality

in another script, if I call for either conn_alchemy or conn_snflk, it shouldn't throw `NameError: name 'conn_alchemy' is not defined`. Instead, I must be able to use the following code without the need to logon again.

```
import pandas as pd
query = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn_alchemy)
```

Comment: I don't see an easy way of doing that. The [storemagic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) works for variables that are pickleable, but a database connection is not. You can use %store for the user credentials but then you will need to open a new connection for each notebook as far as I can see.

Comment: I appreciate that idea @Sergiu... But my intention is to use a single connection to fetch any number of queries from any number of notebooks..

Comment: Are there ways to find pointers to any active/live connection to snowflake from a fresh notebook?